# can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB using WFS

Tags: orientdb, geoserver

Hi i got a new requirement i.e
I want manipulate my spatial data in GeoServer.
is there any way to connect geo server with orient db.
as I know that geo server support few data bases .

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer has no connector for OrientDB (not an official one in the geoserver.org community at least).

That said, it should be possible to develop one mimicking the existing stores for existing spatial databases.

Comment: sorry I am not understand what u have told

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot connect geoserver to orientdb.