# How can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB

Tags: gis, orientdb, geoserver

I need to use Geo Server with Orient DB. I searched I could find Luca's answer (http://orientdb.com/webinars-luca-garulli-2016/) and  Andrea's answer ([can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB using WFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs)) as this is not possible when they answered.

Is it available now to connect Geo Server or GIS server and Orient Db.If not what would alternative to do the same.

If any one can help in this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB using WFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs)

Comment: According to [official documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/index.html) it's not possible.