# Can OrientDB Connected with any Geospatial server like geoserver to expose WFS and WMS

Tags: geospatial, orientdb, openlayers-3, geoserver, orientdb2.2

I have a requirement where I need show data from Geospatial data from Orient DB  and render the same on map with the below futures

I could see there are several tools with oracle db like Openlayer +GeoServer +Oracle Spatial database.

Is there anything as same for orient-db? if yes please suggest the technology /tools stack that can be used to achieve the same functionality with orient DB

Comment: You could probably write an orient datastore to use in geoserver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB using WFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs)