# GEO Server: Can I connect GEO Server with any geo Spatial database by adding data store?

Tags: gis, geoserver, geotools

I want to connect GEO Spatial Database with GEO Server.
GEO Server is not provide out of the box facility for the same. But i want to know the possibility to connect GEO Server with other GEO Spatial database by adding new data store through GEO Tool.

I have seen one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs) stating this can be possible to develop one mimicking the existing stores for existing spatial databases

Comment: what is your question? how does it differ from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs?noredirect=1&lq=1 ? You need to tell us which database you actually want to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can i make Geo server connection with Orient DB using WFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011293/can-i-make-geo-server-connection-with-orient-db-using-wfs)